# Ajax Login With PHP Issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cookies

I am creating A login system using AJAX,PHP & SQL obviously.

Anyway I am trying to implement A real time login feature so it will log the user in without refreshing the page.

I have done that almost but the only issue when the user clicks remember me that uses cookies instead of sessions but the JQuery isn't proccessing that?
I want it to detect depending if it was checked ether remember the user or not it only starts a session, when it does register a cookie the logout page is not deleting the cookie which he did before i added the jquery code in so nothing on the php end and I am mainly A PHP Developer and still learning.
(I cannot post the server side code for privacy reasons as I be using this in A project
but it looks similar to any other normal php login script)

Here's the JQuery

```
function validLogin(){
      var user_login=$('#user_login').val();
      var user_pass=$('#user_pass').val();
      var remember_me=$('#remember_me');


      var dataString = 'user_login='+ user_login + '&user_pass='+ user_pass;



      $("#flash").show();
      $("#flash").fadeIn(100).html('Loading..');
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajax/procces.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(result){
               var result=trim(result);
               $("#flash").hide();
               if(result=='correct'){
                     window.location='index.php';
               }else{
                     $("#errorMessage").html(result);
               }
      }
      });
}

function trim(str){
     var str=str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/,'');
     return str;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You're not doing anything with the "remember me" value.  You capture the element itself into a variable, but never use that variable.  Usually "remember me" functionality sets a cookie.

Comment: I tried added it in dataString but that just forces it to set a cookie whether the box is tick or not and when you try to logout the cookie is still set which is weird
Not sure how to implement it

Comment: `"whether the box is tick or not"` - That depends on how you're adding it, which you don't specify in the question.  `"when you try to logout the cookie is still set"` - Did you ever unset it?

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: get the state of your checkbox: `var remember_me = $('#remember_me').is(':checked')` and add it to your `dataString`

Comment: Thanks ; ) on my phone now but I try this in the morning its late here around 12am (or early)

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass your variable 'remember me' to your ajax request. For instance :

```
data: {login: user_login, passwd: user_pass, rememberMe: remember_me}
```

Another point, be careful you treat information from client-side. Never trust the client. Test all your values in PHP.

Comment: Thanks! There should be a way to get jqyery to load a php page then php can handle it from there and its more safer that way